# jQuery file upload how to get number of files queued and uploaded

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

In jQuery file uploader (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), when I start uploading some files, I want to show a line saying "Uploaded x of y". x is the number of files successfully uploaded, and y is the number of files uploading/queued. How do I get those two numbers? I have looked at the options but I didn't find anything I can use.

If the page is refreshed during or after upload is finished, I also want to show a message called "x files uploaded". So how can I get that number? It would also be good to know how to count number of files failed during upload.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: by simply using $('#table_fileupload tr').length;

Answer (score 4):

Based on [API documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) you can use `"Callback Options"` to bind event during your upload.

```
$('#fileupload')
    .bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadstart', function (e) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadstop', function (e) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadchange', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadpaste', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploaddrop', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploaddragover', function (e) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadchunksend', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadchunkdone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadchunkfail', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadchunkalways', function (e, data) {/* ... */});
    // and some Processing Callback Options
    .bind('fileuploadprocessstart', function (e) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadprocess', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadprocessdone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadprocessfail', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
    .bind('fileuploadprocessstop', function (e) {/* ... */});
```

The one you are looking for is :

> ### add
>
> The add callback can be understood as the callback for the file upload
>   request queue. It is invoked as soon as files are added to the
>   fileupload widget - via file input selection, drag & drop or add API call.

And also :

> ### processdone
>
> Callback for the successful end of an individual file processing
>   queue.
>
> ```
> Example: function (e, data) {
>      console.log('Processing ' + data.files[data.index].name + ' done.'); 
> }
> ```

**Just keep some variable to increment and manage your display.**

Also be careful not forgotting error handling (with ´ process fail´ event) if an error occurs to display proper interface.

To know about how many files you are sending, just use `add events` to keep track of your variable.

*There is some function you can call to have those values but I would not recommend them since event binding has been build specifically to keep your code synchronized at any time.*

### About page refresh

You need to use a `sessionStorage` to keep values when refreshing a page. The easiest way is to update this value everytime your number_of_files change. ([see document on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage))

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

You just need on load (or initialization of your upload plugin) to get this value and set initial value of your variable ... this way it will keep track of previous session.

### Suggestion of code

```
var counter = 0;
var number_of_files = 0; // or sessionStorage.getItem('number_of_files')
$('#fileupload')
    .bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            console.log('Added file in queue: ' + file.name);
            number_of_files = number_of_files + 1;
            sessionStorage.setItem('number_of_files', number_of_files);
        });
    })
    .bind('fileuploadprocessdone', function (e, data) {
        console.log(counter + " / " + number_of_files);
    });
```

You just need to have all case in your code like deletion, modification and other ... to make sure your value is always up to date. But jQuery-File-Upload is not suppose to be in charge of your view, as part of MVC pattern it only do one thing which is uploading and giving you all tools to work with that

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, which is helpful. However I am still struggling to show the total count of files that are already uploaded. For example, after upload is finished, if I refresh the page, I want to display a count for all picture, also if I delete a file, that count should be updated. I tried using `jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload('option').getNumberOfFiles();` and `jQuery("#fileupload .template-download:not('.ui-state-error')").length` but they don't work properly. Any help on that please?

Comment: You need to use all the events to keep track manually of deletion/adding ... If you refresh the page, it is something different because you lose your instance of the page and get a new one. Then you need to give a look at `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` to keep those information when refreshing. Except if you implement two way data binding, it will be difficult to keep your HTML with proper value if you just use getNumberOfFiles().

Comment: I updated my answer to help with this last point ... hope it will be enough.

Comment: Could you manage a way to do so ? Please remind to mark your question as solved, it will help others in the same situation.

Comment: Hi, fileuploadprocessdone did not work for me, I had to use fileuploaddone. Also your suggested code on counting total number of files uploaded is not within $each loop? Furthermore, the sessionStorage works the way you suggested, however, I cannot handle the fail upload, that event is not working when a filetype is not allowed, I don't know why. And I really think that the total count on page refresh should be based on total number of image in the page, or total number of <tr>. Otherwise it will show incorrect count if anything goes wrong. So is there a way to count <tr> on the page?

Answer (score 1):

The total may be displayed using queue.length in the default blueimp front end structure:  (Angular can just do {{queue.length}} in the html).

Keep track of uploads complete with the callbacks in documentation: add 1 on uploaddone, etc.

If you need to track total uploaded between page loads you will need to store that in your app's back-end.  Angular may do this in a service.